# Speed-up numpy matrix multiplication using cython

Tags: python, numpy, performance, cython, matrix-multiplication

I am computing a matrix multiplication at few thousand times during my algorithm. Therefore, I compute:

```
import numpy as np
import time


def mat_mul(mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4):
    return(np.dot(np.transpose(mat1),np.multiply(np.diag(mat2)[:,None], mat3))+mat4)

n = 2000
mat1 = np.random.rand(n,n)
mat2 = np.diag(np.random.rand(n))
mat3 = np.random.rand(n,n)
mat4 = np.random.rand(n,n)

t0=time.time()
cov_11=mat_mul(mat1, mat2, mat1, mat4)
t1=time.time()
print('time ',t1-t0, 's')
```

The matrices are of size:
n = (2000,2000) and mat2 only has entries along its diagonal. The remaining entries are zero.

On my machine I get the following:
`time  0.3473696708679199 s`

How can I speed this up?

Thanks.

Comment: *mat3* isn't used in the example code, is that a typo?

Comment: Please describe your hardware (mainly the exact processor reference though memory infos can help). Such a time would be incredible on a old Raspberry Pi 1, but pretty bad on a 64-core AMD EPIC based HPC computing node ;) . It is all about efficiency: `actual_time / optimal_time`.

Comment: `np.einsum('ki,kk,kl->il', mat1, mat2, mat3, optimize=['einsum_path', (0, 1), (0, 1)]) + mat4` is the fastest `numpy` solution I could find (~1.013x faster on a google colab instance with n=2000). `jax.jit` compiled (only CPU) with `jax` arrays (`return mat1.T @ (jnp.diag(mat2)[:,None] * mat3) + mat4` inside the function) ~2x faster, I think mainly because of operation fusing.

Comment: `jax.jit` compiled on GPU (Tesla T4) ~94x faster (426ms vs 4.54ms), like @AhmedAEK suggested. The benchmark excludes the time to initialize the example arrays on the GPU and used `block_until_ready` to avoid measuring [asynchronous dispatch](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/async_dispatch.html).

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I think the 94x speed up is not possible for float64 on this hardware, especially 4.54ms. Indeed, the T4 float64 performance is ~0.24 Tflops while it is 8.1 Tflops for float32. The optimal time only for the basic matrix multiplication (MM) is 66 ms on such hardware (but 2 ms for float32). So I think you use float32 and the result are not as accurate. Besides, my i5-9600KF processor reach 0.3 Tflops and takes ~100 ms (the optimal is ~40 ms for the float64 MM). 426ms is a bit slow for a mainstream desktop CPU.

Comment: @JérômeRichard - `jax` uses float32 by default and I didn't cast to float64, that's correct. CPUs on google colab are 2-cores of CPU family: 6, Model: 79, Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.20GHz, I think it's a 2016 model (or 2018).

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Ok. It looks like an old Broadwell server processor which have much more core (from 10 up to 24) but you use only 2 of them (virtual CPU). Meanwhile the GPU looks more recent (>2018) and should be fully used. Not sure the comparison is fair ;) .

Comment: I'm afraid using float32 with `jax` is also the main factor in speeding up the CPU computation. The only hint left: using float32 is faster.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny It make sense indeed since x86 CPUs can compute twice float32 items per cycles compared to float64 using SIMD instructions (SSE & AVX). This is because float64 takes twice more space in SIMD lanes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Numpy implementation can be optimized a bit by reducing the amount of **temporary arrays** and **reuse them as much as possible** (ie. multiple times). Indeed, while matrix multiplications are generally **heavily-optimized by BLAS** implementations, filling/copying (newly allocated) arrays add a non-negligible overhead.

Here is the implementation:

```py
def mat_mul_opt(mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4):
    tmp1 = np.empty((n,n))
    tmp2 = np.empty((n,n))
    vect = np.diag(mat2)[:,None]
    np.dot(np.transpose(mat1),np.multiply(vect, mat3, out=tmp1), out=tmp2)
    np.add(mat4, tmp2, out=tmp1)
    return tmp1
```

The code can be optimized further if it is fine to mutate input matrices or if you can pre-allocate `tmp1` and `tmp2` outside the function once (and then reuse them multiple times). Here is an example:

```py
def mat_mul_opt2(mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4, tmp1, tmp2):
    vect = np.diag(mat2)[:,None]
    np.dot(np.transpose(mat1),np.multiply(vect, mat3, out=tmp1), out=tmp2)
    np.add(mat4, tmp2, out=tmp1)
    return tmp1
```

Here are performance results on my i5-9600KF processor (6-cores):

```
mat_mul:                 103.6 ms
mat_mul_opt1:             96.7 ms
mat_mul_opt2:             83.5 ms
np.dot time only:         74.4 ms   (kind of practical lower-bound)
Optimal lower bound:      55   ms   (quite optimistic)
```

Comment: thanks for this answer! What happens if mat1 is additionally symmetric? Can I exploit that somehow or is numpy also doing with this efficiently?

Comment: AFAIK Numpy does not detect that (nor BLAS libraries). I think that in that case `np.transpose` is not needed but BLAS can detect this transposition so it is not faster (but simpler still). There is maybe a mathematical property that might apply in that case, but if so you need to optimize the expression yourself (I am not aware of such a property).

Answer (score 1):

cython is not going to speed it up, simply because numpy is using other tricks to speed things up like threading and SIMD, anyone that tries to implement such function with only cython is going to end up with much worse performance.

only 2 things are possible:

1. use a gpu based version of numpy (cupy)
2. use a different more optimized backend for numpy if you aren't using the best already (like intel MKL)

Comment: Few notes: CuPy requires an Nvidia GPU. float64 computation are only faster on expensive server-side GPUs but generally a slower on desktop GPU. Numpy should use OpenBLAS by default but it is worse checking. The MKL can be a bit faster but the difference is generally small on mainstream platforms for such operations (both are heavily optimized). Cython can speed up the code if the OP rewrite the operation like BLAS does which is tricky (but possible). Cython code can benefit from SIMD instructions though the code may be less well optimized than a BLAS.

Comment: the difference between backends is notable , i once noticed 30% longer time when i changed from MKL to openblas (because a certain project had to be kept below 100 MB including all dependencies), and the code was mainly around addition and multiplication, and maybe some squares and square roots.  anyway the only thing that comes to mind that would speed this up in cython is if the architecture of the CPU is known and the code was written to intentionally abuse the cache line capabilities, but that involves too much coding and would be worse on other CPUs.